# How to Update data and Add new rows

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the `Invoice form` so sometime I want to update the data of the same Invoice number and add now rows.

I want to update the data  and new rows on the same `Invoice No`, on my code below is update and add `one row` instead of add more than one rows which i have selected.

supposed the invoice has one row and i want to update by add 10 rows on that Invoice number, so the code below is works but it update one row and add 1 new row instead of 10(news rows).

My controller of update

```
public function update(Request $request, $inv_no)
{

$data = $request->all();

$date = date ("Y-m-d",  strtotime($request->Indate));

$stocks = Stock::where('inv_no', $inv_no)->get();
$i = 0;

foreach ($stocks as $stock) {  
    Stock::where('inv_no', $inv_no)
        ->where('id', $stock->id)
        ->update([
            'pid' => $request->pid[$i],
            'qty' => $request->qty[$i],
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'Indate'=>$date ,
            'supplierName' => $request->supplierName,
            'receiptNumber' => $request->receiptNumber,
            'truckNumber' => $request->truckNumber[$i],
            'driverName' => $request->driverName,
            'remark' => $request->remark,
        ]);

             $i++;
    }


    $totalPid = count($data['pid']);
    $totalQty = count($data['qty']);
    $totalTruckNumber = count($data['truckNumber']);
 // dd($stocks);

    if (count($stocks) < $totalPid) {
        Stock::create([
            'pid' => $request->pid[$totalPid-1],
            'qty' => $request->qty[$totalQty-1],
            'inv_no' => $request->inv_no,
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'Indate'=>$date,
            'supplierName' => $request->supplierName,
            'receiptNumber' => $request->receiptNumber,
            'truckNumber' => $request->truckNumber[$totalTruckNumber-1],
            'driverName' => $request->driverName,
            'remark' => $request->remark,
        ]);
    }



return  $this->show($inv_no)->with('success', 'GRN  Edited Successfully ');
```

}

below is the Invoice form which i want to Update and Add new rows.
[image]

So I need the help what can i Add there to update and able to add more rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer this it works as well

```
$stockcount= count($stocks);
    $totalPid = count($data['pid']);
    $totalQty = count($data['qty']);
    $totalTruckNumber = count($data['truckNumber']);

    $remain=$totalPid-$stockcount;

    for($i=$stockcount; $i<$totalPid; $i++){      
        Stock::create([
            'pid' => $request->pid[$i],
            'qty' => $request->qty[$i],
            'inv_no' => $request->inv_no,
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'Indate'=>$date,
            'supplierName' => $request->supplierName,
            'receiptNumber' => $request->receiptNumber,
            'truckNumber' => $request->truckNumber[$i],
            'driverName' => $request->driverName,
            'remark' => $request->remark,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am really sorry if i got wrong but why don't you put them in loop if you want more than one.

```
    for($i=0;$i<$how_many_row_should_add;$i++){
if (count($stocks) < $totalPid) {
    Stock::create([
        'pid' => $request->pid[$totalPid-1],
        'qty' => $request->qty[$totalQty-1],
        'inv_no' => $request->inv_no,
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'Indate'=>$date,
        'supplierName' => $request->supplierName,
        'receiptNumber' => $request->receiptNumber,
        'truckNumber' => $request->truckNumber[$totalTruckNumber-1],
        'driverName' => $request->driverName,
        'remark' => $request->remark,
    ]);
}
    }
```

Comment: it still  doing the same, but why are you call this `how_many_row_should_add` or you wnat me to replace with some variable?

Comment: ``array:10 [▼
  "_token" => "GBMOuQQrICXXO8DvV8FoV35VFKWuJXEok1TlF1o7"
  "inv_no" => "GRN3105200005"
  "supplierName" => "dar"
  "receiptNumber" => "98799x"
  "driverName" => "DD"
  "remark" => "OK"
  "Indate" => "2020-05-31"
  "pid" => array:5 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "3"
    3 => "4"
    4 => "5"
  ]
  "truckNumber" => array:5 [▼
    0 => "T 640"
    1 => "T 678"
    2 => "T 220 DRS"
    3 => "T 155"
    4 => "T 640"
  ]
  "qty" => array:5 [▼
    0 => "60"
    1 => "55"
    2 => "40"
    3 => "4"
    4 => "5"
  ]
]

Comment: so  array`[0,1,2]` are in DB, but array`[3,4]` and added and i want to create it

Comment: Yes, I meant replace it with how much rows you want to add. In your example you wanted to add 10 rows but i don't know how you getting this value so that's why i called as $how_many_row_should_add

Comment: ok, i just modify it and added this loop ` for($i=$stockcount; $i<$totalPid; $i++){ ...}` and it works now,,, now you can see my logic there